# Can I roll my current Roth IRA in my name and my spouse's name into a Roth IRA that is only in my spouse's name?

Tags: united-states, investing, roth-ira, rollover

Can I roll my current Roth IRA in my name and my spouse's name into a Roth IRA that is only in my spouse's name?

Comment: Wait a second. Do you think that the current IRA is a joint account?

Comment: Nope. Your is yours and hers is hers. No such thing as joint IRA accounts

Answer (score 7):

No, *you* cannot roll over any money or assets in *your* IRA (of any kind)
into an IRA of any kind in the name of your spouse.  That **I** in IRA stands
for **Individual.**  As mhoran_psprep's comment asks, if by

> "...my current Roth IRA in my name and my  spouse's name..."

you are thinking that you and your spouse *jointly* have an IRA,
you are sadly mistaken; your IRA is yours and your spouse's IRA
belongs to your spouse.  Now, if your spouse is the *beneficiary* of your IRA, 
then **after** your death, your spouse can treat the *inherited* IRA as
if it belonged to the spouse and even rollover the assets into
the spouse's IRA, but this cannot be done during *your* lifetime. And, as
stated upfront, *you* cannot **roll over** money in any IRA of yours
into any kind of IRA belonging to your spouse.

There *is* an
exception to all this in cases of divorce when a state court can issue
a qualified domestic relations order (QDRO) under the laws of that
state requiring some or all of your IRA to be rolled over into
your spouse's IRA, but at that point, it is going to be your *ex*-spouse's
IRA, right? which is not what I think you are asking about.

Comment: Dilip, I'm pretty sure that an **SEP-**IRA can be jointly owned (by all the employees of the "business").  That would go against your "sadly mistaken" comment, for the case of an SEP-IRA (rather than a conventional IRA).

Comment: @PeterK. Since the OP mentioned _Roth_ IRA and did not mention SEP-IRAs at all, I restricted my answer to that. By the way, [the IRS says](http://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/Retirement-Plans-FAQs-regarding-SEPs)  _"A SEP-IRA account is_ **a traditional IRA and follows the same investment, distribution, and rollover rules as traditional IRAs.** _See the IRA FAQs."_  (emphasis added). So, please tell us where you read that SEP-IRAs can be jointly owned.